# Проблема с cin.ignore()

Tags: c++

```
typedef struct{
    char lines[100][256];
    int linesCount;
}text;

    int main() {
            system("chcp 1251>null");
            srand(time(NULL));
            text txt;
            char keyword[256];
            cout << "Enter number of lines:\t";
            cin >> txt.linesCount;
            char f[1];
            for (int i = 0; i < txt.linesCount; ++i) {
                cout << "Enter line №" << i + 1 << "  ";
                cin.ignore();
                gets(txt.lines[i]);
            }
}
```

Столкнулся с проблемой что при считывании начиная с 2 строки txt.lines[1] первый символ пропускается, хотя на первой строке все считывается вполне коректно.

Нашел решение для string

```
string  numnber;
getline(std::cin, number);
```

Есть что-то подобное для char?

Comment: Что-то непонятно - вы вызываете `cin.ignore()` которая выбрасывает первый символ строки, и пишете что это проблема. Вы чего-то другого от этой функции ожидали?

Comment: Я и сам понял что что-то не так, ответ "А что вы ожидали?" не очень то и помог

Answer (score 0):

Както допер сам

```
    int main() {
    system("chcp 1251>null");
    srand(time(NULL));
    text txt;
    char word[256];
    cout << "Enter number of lines:\t";
    cin >> txt.linesCount;
    char f[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.linesCount; ++i) {
        cout << "Enter line №" << i + 1 << "  ";
        do {
            cin >> word;
            strcat(txt.lines[i], word);
            strcat(txt.lines[i], " ");
        } while (cin.get() != '\n');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваше решение - читать по словам - несколько, гм... непрямое.

Вот чтение строки, если уж так нужно именно в массив: `cin.getline(word,256);`

Вот полный код (убрал вашу структуру, чтоб скомпилировать. думаю, вернуть назад не проблема? :)) `ignore()` надо *один раз* - после чтения количества строк.

```
int linesCount;
char word[256];
cout << "Enter number of lines:\t";
(cin >> linesCount).ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
for (int i = 0; i < linesCount; ++i)
{
    cout << "Enter line №" << i + 1 << "  ";
    cin.getline(word,256);

    // Добавляйте, куда надо, она считана:
    cout << "[" << word << "]\n";
}
```